# String processing:How to look up a word if a certain word exists write a dictionary (regular expression)

Tags: python, csv, dictionary, switch-statement

I have a .txt file looks like:

[image: this]

As you can see its a several relationships between the verbs (don't care about the numbers) the file has 5,000 lines.

Data is here: under Download & Use VerbOcean : http://demo.patrickpantel.com/demos/verbocean/

What I want is a dict for each relationship, so that we could say for example

```
similar-to['anger'] = 'energize' 
happens-before['X'] = 'Y'
stronger-than ['A'] = 'B'
```

and so on.

So what I have so far is working perfectly for only [stronger-than] relationship. how should I extend it in a way that does all other relationships as well?

```
import csv

file = open("C:\\Users\\shide\\Desktop\\Independent study\\data.txt")
counter = 1
stronger = {}
strongerverb = []
secondverb = []
term1 = "[stronger-than]" #Look for stronger-than
     words = line.split()  #split sentence
    if term1 in words:  #if ['Stronger-than'] exists in the line then add the first word
     strongerverb.append(line.split(None, 1)[0]) # add only first verb
     secondverb.append(line.split()[2])  #add second verb

     if term1 in words:  # if ['Stronger-than'] exists in the line then add the first word
         strongerverb.append(line.split(None, 1)[0])  # add only first verb
         secondverb.append(line.split()[2])  # add second verb

capacity = len(strongerverb)

index = 0
while index!=capacity:
    line = strongerverb[index]
    for word in line.split():
  #      print(word)
        index = index+1
#print("First verb:",firstverb)
#print("Second verb:",secondverb)
for i in range(len(strongerverb)):
    stronger[strongerverb[i]] = secondverb[i]

#Write a CSV file that fist column is containing verbs that is stronger than the second column.

with open('output.csv', 'w') as output:
     writer = csv.writer(output, lineterminator='\n')
     for secondverb, strongerverb in stronger.items():
        writer.writerow([strongerverb, secondverb])
```

One way is to do same way for all other relationships but I guess that would not be a smart thing. Any ideas? 
what I want is a dict for each relationship, so that we could say:

```
similar-to['anger'] = 'energize' 
happens-before['X'] = 'Y'
stronger-than ['A'] = 'B'
```

I am new to python and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Posting the data as an image is heavily frowned upon.  There is no practical way for us to use the data for testing.  To get the most out of the site it is important to [ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), that includes creating a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example.

Comment: Could you replace the image with an actual sample text?

Comment: You can download the data in the following link. under Download & Use VerbOcean.   click on: Unrefined    http://demo.patrickpantel.com/demos/verbocean/

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using a regular expression:

```
import re
regexp = re.compile(r'^([^\[\]\s]+)\s*\[([^\[\]\s]+)\]\s*([^\[\]\s]+)\s*.*$', re.MULTILINE)
```

- `^`: (At the beginning) means to start looking up in the beginning of the line.
- `$`: (At the end) means that the expression should end at the and of the line.
- `[^\[\]\s]+`: captures all the characters that are not `[`,`]` or spaces. `^` means not to capture the following characters inside the square parentheses.
- We encapsulate the above expression with `()` to mark it as a group to be captured using the `m.groups()`. Since we want to get both verbs and their relationship, we encapsulate those three with `()`.
- Between those groups, we capture all the spaces using `\s*`, and the rest of the line we capture using `.*`. Both being ignored eventually since they are not encapsulated with `()`.

### For example:

```
data = """
invate [happens-beforeg] annex :: ....
annex [similar] invade :: ....
annex [opposite-of] cede :: ....
annex [stronger-than] occupy :: ....
"""
relationships = {}
for m in regexp.finditer(data):
    v1,r,v2 = m.groups()
    relationships.setdefault(r, {})[v1] = v2
print(relationships)
```

### Outputs:

```
{'happens-before': {'invate': 'annex'},
 'opposite-of': {'annex': 'cede'},
 'similar': {'annex': 'invade'},
 'stronger-than': {'annex': 'occupy'}}
```

Then to get the relationship `'similar'` of the verb `'annex'`, use:

```
relationships['similar']['annex']
```

Which will return: `'occupy'`